# Use Domain in Expressjs 4 for NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express

In expressjs 3 I could do

```
var port        = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
var domain      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";

http.createServer(app).listen(port, domain);
```

in express4

```
var server = app.listen(app.get(port), function()
```

how do you add domain in expressjs4

Answer (score 1):

Express 4 almost follows the same thing:

```
var port        = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
var domain      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.listen(port, domain);
```